# Windows has blocked some startup programs

Tags: windows-vista, boot, uac

I put a shortcut to [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm), my graphics card monitoring program, into my startup folder. Every time I start up my computer, Windows pops up a message saying "[Windows has blocked some startup programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930367)". I am then forced to click through a menu to allow MSI Afterburner to run. This defeats the purpose of adding startup programs. It would be much faster to place a shortcut to MSI Afterburner on my desktop and double click it when Windows starts. How do I get rid of this annoying UAC protection on my startup programs?

- Windows Vista Business 64 bit
- Running as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already tried to startup your shortcut from another way? You can set a new key on the folowing path on regedit:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

(the same path you can use on HKLU if you want to just your user auto start your app), or you can use the Windows Task Scheduler, adding a new task that runs on system startup. If you try one of these sugestions don't use your shutcut, get the path that your shutcurt points and paste it directly on regedit or task scheduler.